# How to change the default directory structure of dh_make so that dpkg-buildpackage does not throw any errors

Tags: postgresql, debian-packaging, apache-age

I am trying to create a debian package for a postgreSQL extension [Apache-age](https://github.com/apache/age) release **1.1.1** and created the directory structure using `dh_make` command.
The directory structure is as follows:

```
age-1.1.1 (project root)
├── debian
│   ├── changelog
│   ├── compat
│   ├── control
│   ├── docs
│   ├── examples
│   ├── links
│   ├── manpages
│   ├── menu
│   ├── postinst
│   ├── postrm
│   ├── preinst
│   ├── prerm
│   ├── rules
│   ├── source
│   └── watch
├── src
└── Makefile
```

The `dpkg-buildpackage -b`  when run from project-root folder it looks for debian folder, then reads the rule file, then reads the Makefile located in the project root to build the package.

I want to change the directory structure to the following:

```
.project root
    ├── packaging
    │   ├── debian
    │   │   ├── control
    │   │   ├── control.in
    │   │   ├── changelog
    │   │   ├── copyright
    │   │   ├── pgversions
    │   │   ├── rules
    │   │   └── ...
    │   └──
    ├── src
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── README.md
    ├── Makefile
    └── ...
```

I want to change the directory structure so that the `dpkg-buildpackage -b` command can be run from the packaging folder and it should build the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this but it's working for me:

##### Here are the steps:

- First run the `dh_make_pgxs` command from the project root directory.
- Create a **packaging** directory in the project root and move the **debian** directory created in step 1 to this directory along with the **Makefile**, **age.control** and the **age--1.1.1.sql**.

  Your file structure should look like this:

  ```
    .project root
    ├── packaging
    │   ├── debian
    │   │   ├── control
    │   │   ├── control.in
    │   │   ├── changelog
    │   │   ├── copyright
    │   │   ├── pgversions
    │   │   ├── rules
    │   │   └── ...
    │   ├── age--1.1.1.sql
    │   ├── age.control
    │   ├── Makefile
    │   └── ...
    ├── src
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── README.md
    └── ...
  ```
- Change the file paths in the **Makefile** like:

  - `src/backend/age.o` should be `../src/backend/age.o`.
  - `./tools/` should be `./../tools/`.
  - and so on.
- Now you can simply run the `dpkg-buildpackage -b` command from the **packaging** directory to build the debian package.

Note: In step 1 we are running `dh_make_pgxs` in the project root first, this is to make sure that the project name in the control files and the version in the changelog file are correct. In this case the *name/source* in control, control.in & changelog files should be `apache-age` and the version number in changelog file should be `1.1.1-1`. 
Alternatively, you can run the command from the **packaging** directory and manually change the name and version in the control and changelog files.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, if possible could u please share the make file as well.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `Makefile`

Modify the `install` paths accordingly. It should point to your `packaging/debian/*` where `*` is the filename.

This way the `Makefile` can point to the correct file path target inside the new folder structure.